# setTimeout in a for loop changes final output; how to delay runs of a for loop, without changing final result

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I'm trying to make a custom typewriter effect on my site using a javascript function. In order to add a delay between the typing of each letter, I've implemented a staggered `setTimeout` for each run of the for loop, so each iteration is delayed by an extra 300ms compared to the previous one. I need special characters (' ' '<', '&gt') to be typed as single characters rather than as individual letters, so I have a few `else if` conditions. This produces the desired effect when `setTimeout` is excluded. However, adding the delay results in spelling out the individual letters of this code after printing out the whole character. How can I fix this?

```js
function type(fullTxt, current = '') {
    for (let i = current.length, j = 0; i < fullTxt.length; i++, j++) {
         setTimeout(function() {
            if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+6) === '&nbsp;') {
                console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+6));
                i = i + 5;
            } else if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+4) === '&lt;') {
                console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+4));
                i = i + 3;
            } else if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+3) === '&gt') {
                console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+3));
                i = i + 2;
            } else {
                console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+1));
            }
            console.log(j); //included just to ensure j is counting properly
            console.log(i); //included to check progress of loop
            console.log(fullTxt.length); //included to check endpoint of for loop
         }, j * 300);
    }
}

type('hello&nbsp;');
```

Expected output:

```
// h
// 0
// 0
// 11
// he
// 1
// 1
// 11
// hel
// 2
// 2
// 11
// hell
// 3
// 3
// 11
// hello
// 4
// 4
// 11
// hello&nbsp;
// 5
// 10
// 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safer now is to use `async/await`, calling a `Promise`, this way, your loop is actually waiting for the one before to complete.

Also this makes stuffs easy to write, or later modify.

Timeout set to `2000` ms for the demo.

```js
async function type(fullTxt, current = '') {
    for (let i = current.length, j = 0; i < fullTxt.length; i++, j++) {
            await wait(2000) // Wait for 2000ms
            if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+6) === '&nbsp;') {
                console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+6));
                i = i + 5;
            } else if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+4) === '&lt;') {
                console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+4));
                i = i + 3;
            } else if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+3) === '&gt') {
                console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+3));
                i = i + 2;
            } else {
                console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+1));
            }
            console.log(j); //included just to ensure j is counting properly
            console.log(i); //included to check progress of loop
            console.log(fullTxt.length); //included to check endpoint of for loop       
    }
}

// Generic Promise function
function wait(delayInMS) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delayInMS));
}

type('hello&nbsp;');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `setTimeout` on only the `console.log` rather than around the entire `if` statement.

```js
function type(fullTxt, current = '') {
  for (let i = current.length, j = 0; i < fullTxt.length; i++, j++) {
    if (fullTxt.substring(i, i + 6) === '&nbsp;') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i + 6));
      }, j * 300);
      i = i + 5;
    } else if (fullTxt.substring(i, i + 4) === '&lt;') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i + 4));
      }, j * 300);
      i = i + 3;
    } else if (fullTxt.substring(i, i + 3) === '&gt') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i + 3));
      }, j * 300);
      i = i + 2;
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i + 1));
      }, j * 300);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(j); //included just to ensure j is counting properly
      console.log(i); //included to check progress of loop
      console.log(fullTxt.length); //included to check endpoint of for loop
    }, j * 300);
  }
}

type('hello&nbsp;');
```

Comment: Could've sworn I tried that earlier, but I guess not. It did the trick! Thanks a bunch. Any idea why my code initially kept going past when it was supposed to? I know the setTimeout function still evaluates everything immediately, so does it just run all of the else if conditions separately ahead of time (without checking the conditions against each other) leading to the extra results?

Comment: @RM7 You would had to pass the timeout in a variable, and then use clearTimeout on top of it, when done. But this is typically the source of freezes. I do recommend to use a sound like a short bip to clearly understand what's going on, if you are very curious.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using `async` function

```
 async function type(fullTxt, current = '') {
        for (let i = current.length, j = 0; i < fullTxt.length; i++, j++) {
             await waitFor(j*300);
                if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+6) === '&nbsp;') {
                    console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+6));
                    i = i + 5;
                } else if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+4) === '&lt;') {
                    console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+4));
                    i = i + 3;
                } else if (fullTxt.substring(i, i+3) === '&gt') {
                    console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+3));
                    i = i + 2;
                } else {
                    console.log(fullTxt.substring(0, i+1));
                }
                console.log(j); //included just to ensure j is counting properly
                console.log(i); //included to check progress of loop
                console.log(fullTxt.length); //included to check endpoint of for loop
             }
        }
    


type('hello&nbsp;');
```

here is `waitFor` function

```
function waitFor(ms){
  return new Promise(resolve=> setTimeout(resolve,ms))
}
```